# Does the SoundBlasterX G5 work in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, external-soundcard, sound-blaster

Does anyone know if the SoundBlasterX G5 works on Ubuntu. Seeing as it's an external DAC only the sound needs to be sent to it. Will that mean it's easy to use on Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/X-Fi which explains how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this thing works flawlessly in Ubuntu :D

Just plug and play. It does help to dual boot with windows though so you can use the software to set your three profiles.